# Subject display of Google Analytics data for returning visitors to condition

Tags: google-analytics

Is there a way to display the users returning to my website with a special condition, that is:

only those who have already visited my payment confirmation page (eg. `mysite.com/paiement.confirm`).

My analytics is plugged with the e-commerce thing.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you use custom variables, this is not possible, since Advanced Segments are visit based and not visitor based. Custom variables can however be set to be visitor specific.

E.g. you set custom var 1 to visitor level on the specified page according to Google's instructions (please use async code), examples here:
http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/gaTrackingCustomVariables.html

Actual code sample (added to the page code, before "_trackPageview"):

...

```
 _gaq.push(['_setCustomVar',
      1,                   // This custom var is set to slot #1.  Required parameter.
      'Returning purchasing visitor',     // The name acts as a kind of category for the user activity. Required parameter.
      'Yes',               // This value of the custom variable.  Required parameter.
      1                    // Sets the scope to visitor-level.  Optional parameter.
   ]);
```

...

Answer (score 2):

Custom variable name should be Visitor Type and the value should be Buyer. You need to create a new custom report and drill-down as first dimension should be Visitor Type and the second Dimension shoulde be Custom Variable 1 Value.

With the example above, you didn't know that if he/she is a returning visitor or not.

If you want to analyze exact returning buyers, you may use "getCustomVar" as if he/she has made a purchase or not and then you may set him/her as 'Returning Purchasing Visitor'